# Error while Installing Kivy with pip on GalliumOS

Tags: python, python3, pip

I'm installing Kivy on my laptop running GalliumOS and when I do

```
pip install kivy
```

It gives me all of this stuff. I'm new to Linux and Python so I have no idea what any of this really means.

```
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Using distutils

Detected Cython version 0.23.4
Using this graphics system: OpenGL
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found


WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sdl2' found
Package SDL2_ttf was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_ttf.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'SDL2_ttf' found
Package SDL2_image was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_image.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'SDL2_image' found
Package SDL2_mixer was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_mixer.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'SDL2_mixer' found


 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/tmp/pip-build-4Vxs2J/kivy/setup.py", line 934, in <module>
     version=get_version(),
   File "/tmp/pip-build-4Vxs2J/kivy/setup.py", line 47, in get_version
     ['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
     process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4Vxs2J/kivy/
```

All I'm trying to do is install Kivy. I do have pip installed because I've used pygame a bit in the past.

Is there any easy way to fix this? I'm not too keen on digging into the files but I will if I have to so that this will work.

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

> No package {gstreamer-1.0.pc, sdl2.pc, SDL2_ttf.pc, SDL2_image.pc,
>   SDL2_mixer.pc}

I.e. `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/[files].pc` .

`sudo apt-get install apt-file` : Then you can use `apt-file search [file.pc]` to list the [packages]**-dev** required for Kivy. ( Probably like libgstreamer0.10-dev, libsdl2-dev, etc.)